# Problema con el eje de categorías de un gráfico de lineas con chart js

Tags: jquery, chart.js

Saludos, estoy trabajando con el plugin 'chart js' con gráfico de lineas, tengo dos problemas

**1:** el eje de categorías no muestra los datos correctamente omite algunas categorías cuando es mas pequeño (**imagen 1**), aunque si el 'div' que contiene el 'canvas' tiene un 100% del ancho esto no ocurre (**imagen 2**), pero no tiene que tomar el 100% sino un 70%, ¿Cómo podría configurar esto para que no ocurra?;

**2:**(Sin mucha prioridad) quiero mostrar un cuadro con la definición de las categorías como en la (**imagen 3**), pero no he encontrado información para esto, ¿Alguna idea para realizarlo?.

**Imagen 1**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Imagen 2**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Imagen 3**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Código jquery**

```
var datosDinamo=[];
                    var datosDinamoIdeal=[];
                    var labelsDinamo=[];
                    var labelsDinamoDef=[];
                    var bacground=[];
                    var bacground2=[];
                    var dtst=[];
                    $.each(notas.califica,function(key,valor){
                        datosDinamo.push(valor)
                        datosDinamoIdeal.push(7)
                        labelsDinamo.push(notas.descripcion[key])
                        labelsDinamoDef.push(notas.definicion[key])
                        bacground.push(getRandomColor())

                    })

console.log(datosDinamo) //eje de valores
/*
0
:
"7"
1
:
"2"
2
:
"5"
3
:
"6.5"
4
:
"7"
5
:
"4"
6
:
"6.5"
*/
console.log(labelsDinamo)eje de categorias
/*
0
:
"Asistencia"
1
:
"Rendimiento"
2
:
"Autonomía"
3
:
"Cooperacion"
4
:
"Respeto a las personas"
5
:
"Respeto a las normativas"
6
:
"Capacidad de aprendizaje"
*/
console.log(labelsDinamoDef)//cuadro de definiciones no he encontrado una solucion o ejemplo
/*
0
:
"Relación de días de trabajo efectivo en el periodo v/s fallas y permisos"
1
:
"Capacidad parar ejecutar su trabajo con el ritmo y la calidad esperadas."
2
:
"Capacidad para ejecutar su trabajo de manera efectiva sin necesidad de supervisión constante."
3
:
"Disposición para aceptar nuevas tareas y funciones y ayudar a los demás."
4
:
"Capacidad para comunicarse respetuosamente con compañeros, jefes o subordinados."
5
:
"Capacidad de ejecutar su trabajo de acuerdo a los procedimientos establecidos y a las normas de seguridad vigentes."
6
:
"Habilidad para desarrollar efectiva y reponsablemente funciones y tareas nuevas."
*/
                    var grafico = $('#grafico')
                    var BarraCri = new Chart(grafico,{
                        type:'line',
                        data:{
                            datasets:[{
                                label:'Notas obtenidas',
                                data:datosDinamo,
                                backgroundColor:"rgba(192,192,192,0.5)",
                            },{
                                label:'Notas Ideales',
                                data:datosDinamoIdeal,
                                backgroundColor:'rgba(192,192,192,0.3)',
                            }],
                            labels: labelsDinamo
                        },
                        options: {
                            responsive:true,
                            title: {
                              display: true,
                              text: 'Evaluación tecnica',
                              fontSize:40
                            },
                            scales: {                           
                                yAxes: [{
                                    display: true,
                                    ticks: {
                                        beginAtZero: true,
                                        steps: 1,
                                        max: 7
                                    }
                                }]
                            }
                         }
                    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los datos los está mostrando bien. Lo que está omitiendo son algunas **etiquetas del eje X**.

En `xAxes` las etiquetas corresponden a los `ticks`. Y la propiedad que permite o no omitir algunas para visualizar mejor el gráfico es `autoSkip`. Está documentado en [*Tick Configuration*](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/#tick-configuration).

La propiedad es:

```js
Chart.options.scales.xAxes[0].ticks.autoSkip = false
```

Expresado en el objeto:

```js
Chart(grafico, {
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          autoSkip: false
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

Y, en tu ejemplo:

```js
//eje de valores
var datosDinamo = ["7", "2", "5", "6.5", "7", "4", "6.5"];
var datosDinamoIdeal = [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7];
//eje de categorias
var labelsDinamo = [
  "Asistencia",
  "Rendimiento",
  "Autonomía",
  "Cooperacion",
  "Respeto a las personas",
  "Respeto a las normativas",
  "Capacidad de aprendizaje"
];
//cuadro de definiciones
var labelsDinamoDef = [
  "Relación de días de trabajo efectivo en el periodo v/s fallas y permisos",
  "Capacidad parar ejecutar su trabajo con el ritmo y la calidad esperadas.",
  "Capacidad para ejecutar su trabajo de manera efectiva sin necesidad de supervisión constante.",
  "Disposición para aceptar nuevas tareas y funciones y ayudar a los demás.",
  "Capacidad para comunicarse respetuosamente con compañeros, jefes o subordinados.",
  "Capacidad de ejecutar su trabajo de acuerdo a los procedimientos establecidos y a las normas de seguridad vigentes.",
  "Habilidad para desarrollar efectiva y reponsablemente funciones y tareas nuevas."
];
/*
var bacground = [];
var bacground2 = [];
var dtst = [];
*/


var grafico = $('#grafico')
var BarraCri = new Chart(grafico, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Notas obtenidas',
      data: datosDinamo,
      backgroundColor: "rgba(192,192,192,0.5)",
    }, {
      label: 'Notas Ideales',
      data: datosDinamoIdeal,
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(192,192,192,0.3)',
    }],
    labels: labelsDinamo
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Evaluación tecnica',
      fontSize: 40
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        display: true,
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          steps: 1,
          max: 7
        }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        display: true,
        ticks: {
          autoSkip: false
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Chart.js -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>


<!-- HTML -->
<canvas id="grafico"></canvas>
```

---

Para la leyenda, hay opciones muy variadas. Te recomiendo leer [*Legend Configuration*](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html). Por ejemplo, la última opción en esa página muestra cómo devolver un html a mostrar en la leyenda.